# How can I make new/separate folders in the gallery?

Tags: gallery, external-sd

I recently had some issues with my LG Marquee and had to copy the SD Card's contents to my PC, then put those contents onto a new SD Card to salvage my media content(photos, videos, apps, etc.) When I inserted the new SD Card with my content on it, my phone took the content but it all (all 3,548 items) were placed into *one* single folder in my Gallery.

My question is: **How can I separate/organize these items into new and separate folders in the Gallery?**

Is there a specific way on my phone that I can do this, or do I need to download a photo organizing app? If so, what photo organizing apps are safe and secure?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

My work-around is connect my phone via USB mode, where it comes up as a folder (or volume for you Mac fans) that you can see contents in. Create folders you'd like to have in your gallery, like "Favorite Piks" or "Stuff I found in my pockets" - whatever. Put these in that folder.

Now use your computer to organize the images between folders within that main volume, save on your home computer, delete, so forth.

When you detach from the USB link, your gallery on the phone should show those new folders you created and the images you transferred over.

Please note that any NEW images, photos you download or take with the phone will likely be placed in one of any generic folders like "Downloads" or "Pictures".

## t0mm13b's Edit

Pre-requisites:

- [ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40024/whats-adb-and-why-is-it-used-for-how-do-i-install-it-on-my-device/40051#40051) is installed.
- comfortable with Command line.

By going onto the command line, and issue this command:

`adb shell am start -n com.android.development/.MediaScannerActivity`

The above command line will force Android to re-read the SDCard and quickly re-index all the just transferred pictures into the Gallery.

Comment: Sounds very ranty.... care to re-edit your answer! And for goodness sake, break up those sentences to make it easier to read. :)

Comment: I have re-edited your answer to remove rants and included extra information!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to open my Gallery, but couldn't see any pictures on it.

Anyway, I use the [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder) app to manage my photos. It is able to show the different folders that have pictures in it. Check it out.

Comment: Maybe the QuickPic app overrides the default "Gallery"? I have loads of pics in the "Gallery" and many of the "albums" within it are managed by other apps... "Camera", "WhatsApp Images", "Screenshot", "QrDroid", etc. as well as all my Picassa albums.

Comment: ... Many of these "albums" are virtual and don't actually exist as folders on the device - at least not in the same way they are represented in the "Gallery".

Answer (score 0):

I used Pics organizer to organize my pictures into different folders for my gallery. Download it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.juacali.primetech) works well with other gallery apps.

Answer (score -2):

[CamStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sagar.mehar.camera2) does that job perfectly.

Comment: If you are affiliated with this app, please disclose that.