# How can I access the files in "/data/data" and copy them into memory card without root?

Tags: applications, file-management

Are there any way to access the files in `/data/data` and copy them into memory card? I do not have root access.

Answer (score 40):

Without root access you have 2 options. Both options (may) allow you to access the files for a particular app, e.g. the folder `/data/data/com.app.packagename`.

1. If the application is debuggable you can use the `run-as` command in adb shell (more info about what adb is and how to install it can be found [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40024/7574))

   ```
   adb shell
   run-as com.your.packagename` 
   cp /data/data/com.app.packagename/
   ```
2. If the application is not debuggable, you can use Android's backup function.

   ```
   adb backup -noapk com.app.packagename
   ```

   You will now be prompted to 'unlock your device and confirm the backup operation'. It's best NOT to provide a password, otherwise it becomes more difficult to read the data. Just click on 'backup my data'. The resulting 'backup.ab' file on your computer contains all the app's data in android backup format. Basically it's a compressed tar file. [This page](http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html) explains how you can use OpenSSL's zlib command to uncompress it. 
   You can use the  `adb restore backup.db` command to restore the backup.

Comment: Does this also apply to applications with `android:allowbackup="false"`?

Comment: @Drejon No, I don't think it will work in that case (but I haven't tested it, so I am not 100% sure).

Comment: I am sure there are some cases of application that don't allow backup. When creating backup of all apps, they simply backup nothing. AFAIK, some app might provide a restricted subset of files or maybe even something custom, so don't consider it as always 1:1 of the directory in /data/data. BTW, BlackBerry forces me to use some password, but it is possible to decrypt it (if you have the password). I think I have used https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/ for that.

Comment: I managed to get it with 

adb backup -noapk com.app.packagename

You will get backup.ab then you will need to convert to tar (to open it with 7zip)
You can convert it with https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/ - there is jar inside thi called  abe.jar.
Then You can run command


java -jar abe.jar unpack backup.ab backup.tar

Comment: If `adb backup` produces a tiny (41-47 byte) file, then it may be that the APK is marked as `allowBackup=0`. Run `aapt dump xmltree whatever.apk AndroidManifest.xml | grep allowBackup`.

Comment: According to the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element), you can't disable device-to-device migration of your app's files, so even with `allowBackup="false"`, you can back up to a secondary device of your choice (i.e. a rooted one) and get the files from there.