# I want to access the data of Metamask

Tags: applications, data

I want to have access to the data of the Wallet MetaMask on my android phone. After an error occured I can't enter my wallet. This error occured:

Metamask encountered an error due to reaching a storage limit. The local data has been corrupted. Please reinstall Metamask and restore with your secret recovery phrase.

Sonce I don't have my recovery phrase I try access the data. If I had used a browser extention I could have used the vault decryptor. But I only use Metamask on my mobile android phone (Samsung S10 Android14).

Is it possible to get the folder or read the data when the phone is not rooted? Can someone tell me how? I read questions asked here before but I can't get the data.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access the files in "/data/data" and copy them into memory card without root?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48609/how-can-i-access-the-files-in-data-data-and-copy-them-into-memory-card-withou)